# Enable https in Windows Service hosted WCF

Tags: wcf, https

I'm running a WCF Service hosted in a Windows Service (no IIS). I need to enable https (currently only http). I've tried several changes but non of them works. I'm pasting my app.config file. Any help will be much appreciated.
Regards

````
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="TEST" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="default" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="extern" name="Eps.EDN.Extern">
        <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:6081" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpExtern" bindingNamespace="http://test.com.ar/Extern" contract="Eps.EDN.IExtern" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="extern">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://127.0.0.1:6102" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TEST" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.200)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));Pooling=True;Connection Timeout=60;Min Pool Size=10;">
    </add>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MaxRecs" value="30">
    </add>
    <add key="00" value="EpsService.EDN.DLL,Eps.EDN.EpsInternal">
    </add>
    <add key="01" value="EpsService.EDN.ReportEngine.DLL,Eps.EDN.Reporting.ReportEngine">
    </add>
    <add key="02" value="EpsService.EDN.External.DLL,Eps.EDN.Extern">
    </add>
  </appSettings>
  <TEST key="3277A1E64F3C1455DBF03E7FF2F14135235E2DA4C3A8468D49488584DB6CDEB3" ID="1" />
</configuration>```
````

Comment: You need to use `https`, of course, and then you need a binding that has `<security mode="Transport">`, probably, and probably with a clientCredentialType of Certificate, but that depends how you want to authenticate - there are many options. Bottom line: it's best to find a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried several ways i found in this site but o get error 1064 while starting the service. I will use a SSL self signed certificate.

Comment: Possibly an assembly binding error - you may want to check the Windows event log when this happens.

Comment: The error 1064 is not very specific. You can use `EventViewer` to fetch more detailed error messages and find the reason why the service failed.